# Didn’t understand constraint relation here

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, string

[image]

[image]

2nd image is the way solved in book but not mine.

I didn’t get that why $x_2$ is acc of block of mass 2 kg and why $x_2$ is comparable with block of mass 2 kg.

$x_2$ is the length of string for mass 2 kg. But is $l_3$ which is not same as $x_2$.

Neither can we say that $2x_4 - x_1 = x_2$?

Answer (score 0):

In a constraint problem, we choose a desired reference and mark the distances of blocks, pullys present. This distances acts like the position 'vector' for the component. By just looking at a problem we know that certain relation constraints those distances together. This constraint is the length of the string which remains constant throughout the motion. To find the constraint relation we usually start by constructing these constant by using our distances.

In this problem, $x_2$ is the distance that we mark from the refrence line or choosen origin (the dotted line in figure) and is not the length which  connects block with the rest of system. The $l_3$ is the string that goes over pulley 4 and then is connected on block 1.

This clears why $2x_4 -x_1\neq x_2$

Comment: Then why is x2 acc also a2 , therefore acc of 2kg mass

Comment: $x_2$ is not $a_2$, the Diffrentiation of $x_2$ twice with time leads to $a_2$, because that's what we wish for, we need acceleration of block in order to solve the sys. Think it this way, as the system moves the block 2 accelerates, this indeed changes $x_2$ that is the length we mark from reference.